# Event Viewer ID for start events

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, eventviewer

What is the Event ID code in the Windows Event Viewer that will tell me:

Server has started
IIS has started

Is there a place online where I can look these things up?

Thanks!

Chris

Answer (score 1):

Well, you surely know about [Microsoft Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/default.aspx) and their effort of an [Event ID search](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/support/ee/ee_advanced.aspx). The site [eventid.net](http://eventid.net/) (free and paid contents) might also be no news for you.

You specifically asked about a list of Event-IDs. That now depends on your Windows (and IIS) version which you didn't provide. The free Windows 2003 Server Security Guide (see technet under Security Products and Technologies) lists quite a few of them and the second edition of the Windows Security Resource kit has a lot of information on auditing and event ID's. It is not free (see amazon.com) but worth a read.

Some general info on auditing can be found in the [Security Monitoring and Attack Detection Planning Guide](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc163158.aspx).